# Android - Calendar возвращает неверные данные

Tags: android, java, календарь

Облазил весь гугл, только ещё больше запутался. Дело в том, что Calendar возвращает неверные данные.
Вот мой код:
    mCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    mDate = new Date();

```
int month = mCalendar.MONTH;
int dayofweek = mCalendar.DAY_OF_WEEK;
int day = mCalendar.DAY_OF_MONTH;
int hour = mDate.getHours();
int min = mDate.getMinutes();
int sec = mDate.getSeconds();

mMonth.setProgress(month);
mDayOfWeek.setProgress(dayofweek);
mDay.setProgress(day);
mHour.setProgress(hour);
mMinute.setProgress(min);
mSecond.setProgress(sec);
Log.e("DBG", "" + month + "|" + dayofweek + "|" + day + "|" + hour + "|" + min + "|" + sec);
```

Что я получаю в логе:

```
DBG 2|7|1|22|52|34
```

Хотя должно быть вот так

```
DBG 1|5|31|22|52|34
```

Где я допустил ошибку и почему дата возвращается неверно?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Все очень просто - mCalendar.MONTH - это не текущий месяц. Это константа для номера поля внутри объекта.  Вам нужен метод `get`, которому параметром эту константу нужно и передать.

```
int month = mCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
```

Почему так странно сделано? да все просто. Иначе пришлось бы делать кучу методов. set/get/add для дней/месяцев.